# VS2010 project in VS2012 - different version of .net 4?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have read that opening a vs2010 project in vs2012 is fine (as long as you are using VS2010 SP1) it will not update the project files and those on VS2010 SP1 will not have problems using it: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/01/more-power.aspx

However I have heard that the version of .net 4 is higher when using vs 2012 than with vs2010 (I don't mean .net 4.5 by the way). Is this correct and could it cause problems with a release on a development machine being tested against a different version of the .net 4 framework? It sounds a bit unlikely to me.

thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not simple. All the details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

There are many different types of projects in VS, and some don't require upgrades, some are compatible but require upgrades, and some are simply not compatible. It depends on the project type.

Also, to answer your question about the .net versions, 4.5 is considered an "in place" upgrade. This means once you've installed 4.5, it replaces 4 completely. So, once you've installed 4.5 you use that any time you target 4.

Answer (score 0):

Several bugs has been fixed with .NET 4.5, so suddenly you cannot reproduce bugs that people experience in live-environment (WinXP/Win2k3 - .NET 4.0), as your own machine that have VS2012 installed (.NET 4.5).

More Info [If I target .net 4.0 but run on a machine that has .net 4.5 will .net 4.0 WPF bugs still be there?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a)

More Info [Make VS2012 not hide .NET 4.0 bugs when targeting .NET 4.0](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3095632-make-vs2012-not-hide-net-4-0-bugs-when-targeting-)

More Info [Support a .NET 4.0 Service Pack on Windows XP Supporting those .NET 4.0 Bugs Fixed in .NET 4.5](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3127346-support-a-net-4-0-service-pack-on-windows-xp-supp)